# Merge 2 html pages' css & javascript codes properly

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have 2 html pages. first one is `main.html` which is my homepage. in Second one, i created a `textarea` with its own `css` styling and `javascript` functions. and i want to include this textarea into `main.html`. İ created it seperately because its styling and JS codes are already too big and i did not want to create a congestion in `main.html`.

```
main.html                                                text.html
<html>                                                   <style>
<head>                                                     //CSS codes
  <style>                                                </style>
    //some css in there
    //want to add text.html's css codes in there                                  
  </style>                                               <div>
</head>                                                    <textarea>
<body>                                                     </textarea>
  <div>some content in here</div>                           </div>
  <div>some content in here</div>                           
  <div>some content in here</div>                           <script>
                                                           //JS codes                      
                                                         </script>
  <script> 
    //some javascript goes there
    //want to add text.html's js codes there
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i know that i can use php's include function like `<?php include 'text.html'; ?>` inside `main.html` or i can use `<iframe>`. But with both solutions, `<style>` and `<script>` tags appears in the middle of `main.html` which is an ugly and unwanted scene. Thats exactly whats my main problem in here. i want to put `text.html`'s CSS codes inside `main.html`'s `<style>` tag as well as `text.html`'s js codes into `main.html`'s `<script>` tag. Is there anything that will do this magic touch?

Comment: Please do not use expletives in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** use `<style>` and `<script>` and then put your CSS / JS between them.

Instead, create new files: `text.css` and `text.js` for `text.html`, and `main.css` and `main.js` for `index.html` (you can choose what to name these files, as long as they end in either `js` for JavaScript or `css` for CSS).

You should then put all JavaScript files into a folder named `js` and all CSS files into a folder named `css`. Again, the names do not really matter.

Your file structure should now look somewhat like this:

```
|index.php
|includes
    |text.html
|css
    |main.css
    |text.css
|js
    |main.js
    |text.js
```

Now, when you need the styles, use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

(or `css/text.css`, of course) where you would otherwise have had your `<style>` tags.

Similarly for JavaScript, use

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

(or `js/text.js` to include that one) where you would otherwise have had your `<script>` tags.

---

Your `text.html` file should now not contain any script or styling content, nor links to the files (`index.php` should have all of the links).

So now, just do

```
<?php
    include("includes/text.html");
?>
```

to include the HTML content.

Comment: yeah i thought about that but it looks like alotta work to do.

Comment: The alternative would be to write about 50+ lines of javascript to dynamically and asynchronously include only the CSS tags and inject them into the CSS of the `main.html`, then include only the Script tags and inject them into the JS of `main.html`. Your call.

Comment: @GaiKuroda It should take you about 10 minutes max if you just follow these instructions line-by-line, and once you've done it, it'll be easier to do for future pages on your website.